# Removing components not updating JPanel/JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I had a larger program where i encounterd a weird bug, i managed to isolate it into this small code line but from here i can't say what i'm doing wrong.

The problem is that for some reason the JFrame/JPanel forgets to update it's graphics when adding and removing a panel from it. it works if i don't set a preferred size for the "pbase" panel and or fixes itself if i resize the window while it's removed.

what am i missing?

```
public class ADdREMOVEJPANELS extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ADdREMOVEJPANELS();
}
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JPanel pbase = new JPanel();
public ADdREMOVEJPANELS(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.addKeyListener(this);

    p.setBackground(Color.red);
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

    pbase.setBackground(Color.blue);
    pbase.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pbase.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    pbase.add(p);

    this.setBackground(Color.green);
    this.add(pbase);


    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        System.out.println("works");
        pbase.remove(p);
        pbase.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.pack();

    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        System.out.println("worksdouble");
        pbase.add(p);
        this.pack();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please consider creating and posting a valid [mre] with your question. This is not the entire program but rather a small sub-set that has a main method and complete class structure, that compiles, runs and demonstrates the problem, and that is small enough to be allowed in its entirety within your question. Please check out the link which will explain both the details of this construct and how it can help both you and us.

Comment: is this better? it was all there except the main call and class extensions but now thats there too

Comment: You're forgetting to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` pbase after making the changes.

Comment: `pbase.revalidate();
   pbase.repaint();`

Comment: But yes, that is better code, thank you.

Comment: Yep thats it. thank you, thank you, thank you.